# Notice: Undefined index, why?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a library system, everything is going well, but I faced with such a error

> Notice: Undefined index: user_log in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\e_library\top.php on line 23

and line 23 is here:

```
<?php 
$user_log = $_SESSION['user_log'];
if (isset($_SESSION['user_log'])){
    echo "<a href='#' style='color:#FFC'>Welcome $_SESSION[username] </a> ||  <a href='logout.php' style='color:#FFC'>Logout</a>";
}
else{
    echo "<a href='login.php' style='color:#FFC'>Sign In</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're using `$_SESSION['user_log'];` before you check it exists.

Comment: [**YOU WIN A COOKIE**](http://static.tumblr.com/af06dd0807d256dc1dec8abe12cd8f1b/oghd6vg/FBSmgqgxn/tumblr_static_chocolate_chip_cookies.jpeg) Have fun with it @andrewsi !

Answer (score 1):

You should put `$user_log = $_SESSION['user_log'];` *inside* your `if (isset($_SESSION['user_log']))` block, instead of *before*.

Comment: That would be my first response, too; but the `$user_log` variable isn't used in the snippet we can see. What I'd suggest would be to initialise it outside the `if` to blank, too - otherwise, you risk an `undefined variable` message from further down the code.

Comment: Also, in the if statement he has $_SESSION[username] and username should be in quotes.

Comment: Ya...the snippet has shown more than one issue

Answer (score 0):

Please check first:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_log'])){ // Because session array does not contain this yet.
        //welcome message and $user_log = ..
}else{

}
```

Comment: tnx, you mean , I should use nested if?

Comment: no, i think the previous answer is identical to mine. only the $user_log should be inside if block. :)
 
Note: Actually $_SESSION array does not contains the index 'user_log', so it says an undefined index.